# How to detect that stdio was redirected to nul?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, stdout

I'm developing a package to fix several issues with Unicode in Python run in standard Windows console environment: https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console. The key operation is to replace the standard stream objects when needed. For this I need to detect whether the standard streams were redirected or not. Python method `isatty()` works OK with one exception: If a stream was redirected to `nul`, then `isatty()` returns `True`.

My question is how to detect whether a Windows handle leads to a console or to `nul`? Is there a WinAPI function for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C runtime's [`_isatty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew) function returns true for files that access character devices, i.e. files for which [`GetFileType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364960) returns `FILE_TYPE_CHAR`. To detect a console handle in particular you can call [`GetConsoleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167). This call fails for a non-console handle. To get the underlying Windows handle to pass to this function, call [`msvcrt.get_osfhandle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.get_osfhandle). For example:

```python
import ctypes
import msvcrt

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE = 6

def is_console(file_descriptor):
    handle = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(file_descriptor)
    if kernel32.GetConsoleMode(handle, ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_uint())):
        return True
    last_error = ctypes.get_last_error()
    if last_error != ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(last_error)
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you again. I currently use `kernel32.GetLastError` and `kernel32.GetStdHandle` instead of `ctypes.get_last_error` and `msvcrt.get_osfhandle`, respectively. Is there a reason to prefer one over another?

Comment: @user87690, I could change the answer to use `GetStdHandle`. The C runtime tries to keep file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 in sync with Windows `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError`. But a program might manually call `SetStdHandle`, bypassing the CRT. Which do you prefer, to use the handle associated with the C standard file descriptor, or to always use the Windows standard handle?

Comment: @user87690, as to calling `GetLastError` directly, that's generally OK. However, there is a lot of code between high-level Python statements, so I prefer to load the DLL with `use_last_error=True` to capture the thread's last error in a thread-local variable. ctypes swaps this thread-local in via `SetLastError` just before calling the target function, and swaps it back out via `GetLastError` just after the call. It's accessed by calling `ctypes.get_last_error` and `ctypes.set_last_error`.